# a syntax error, am I missing a package?

Tags: floats, positioning

```
\begin{table}[h+]
```

This gives a syntax error in pdflatex. I guess I am missing a package, but I cannot think which one it is. I have installed every package I can think of ....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE `+` seems to be wrong! I don't know this float parameter.

Comment: I'm curious where you saw `+` used as a float specifier, I've never seen it before. Any subset of `htbp!` is valid without packages.

Comment: I can only assume that what you were meant (or supposed) to type was `\begin{table}[h!]`. That, or one or more of the following letters: `h`, `t`, `b`, and `p`. For sure , if you use `!` instead of `+`, the syntax error is gone.

Comment: I might also add that using [h] or [h!] will cause the table to go the end of the section/chapter/document or wherever the next \clearpage is if it will not fit on the current page.  If you don't want it to float, don't use table at all.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Your comment is correct for `[h]` but (thankfully for lots of unsuspecting users) not for `[h!]`: LaTeX automatically changes all instances of `[h!]` to `[ht!]`. The effect of `[ht!]`: if LaTeX can't place the float "right here" on the current page, it *will* place it at the top of the very next next page.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Up to LaTeX release 2015/01/01, an input such as

```
\begin{table}[h+]
```

wouldn't have produced an error, but the `+` would have done nothing at all.

Starting from that release, illegal characters in the optional argument to a float environment (`table`, `figure` or others defined by additional packages) produce an error

```
Unknown float option `<opt>'
```

in your case

```
Unknown float option `+'
```

Note that the *only* legal characters are

```
h t b p !
```

With the `float` package, one can use `H` (alone), but it's not recommended.

Comment: I have been using the + for ages! OH OK maybe it was simply being ignored. Was told by someone it made the placement stronger back in about 2003....

Comment: @Robin That's `!`, not `+`.